# NumberRangeFilter giving "One or more participants failed to draw() error"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

Using Visual Studio 2015 MVC Core 1.1

_Layout.cshtml

1. Load Javascript APIs loads for the site.
2. Here I call `google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls'] });`
3. Environment Variables set to "Development" in the project properties.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
         <!-- Javascript -->
         <environment names="Development">
                <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
                <script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <script src="~/lib/clipboard/dist/clipboard.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>    
                   @*<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?ext.js"></script>*@          
                <script type="text/javascript">
                       google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls'] });
                </script>
                <script src="~/lib/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
                <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>                @*Production bundles to site.min.js - always last*@
                <script src="~/js/Script_CodeStudio.js"></script>   @*Production bundles to site.min.js - always last*@
                <script src="~/js/Script_Gcharts.js"></script>      @*Production bundles to site.min.js - always last*@
               </environment>

         <!-- Javascript Page Specific Header-->
         @RenderSection("scripts_head", required: false)
   </head>
   <body>

   <!-- CONTENT -->
   @RenderBody() 

   <!-- Javascript Page Specific Body-->
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   ```

Index.cshtml

1. Contains `<div>` id's needed to render dashboard
2. Contains callback `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback();`

   ```
   <div id="div_dashboard_Detail">
         <div id="div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker1"></div><br />
         <div id="div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker2"></div><br />
         <div id="div_dashboard_Detail_chart"></div>
      </div>

      @section scripts_head{
       <script>
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);
           function gChart0() {
               drawChart_LogsSelectingEvents_MissedDelivery_test();
           };
       </script>
      }
   ```

Google Dashboard function:

1. I'm trying to load a `NumberRangeFilter` called `categoryPicker2` but get the error `One or more participants failed to draw()`
2. If I remove `categoryPicker2` and leave `categoryPicker1`, the table renders just fine.

x

```
function drawChart_LogsSelectingEvents_MissedDelivery_test() {

    var urlString = '../Logs/clnLogsSelectingEvents?grade=All&SC=1&CauseSC=3';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        //url: urlString,       //I have commented out but this is my original source.
        success: function (result) {

            //Create DataTable
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            //Add Columns
            data.addColumn('string', 'Review on Week');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Business Division');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Product');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Cause');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Next Step');  //inserted
            data.addColumn('string', 'Carrier Reference or Responsible');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Cost');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Age (d)');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Delivery Number');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Material Description');
            data.addColumn('string', '');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Actual State');

            //Add Rows
            var dataArray = [];
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //manually push data into table
                dataArray.push([
                  'string1',
                  'string2' + i,
                  'string3',
                  'string4',
                  'string5',
                  'string6',
                  10,
                  20,
                  5 + i,
                  'string7',
                  'string8',
                  'string9',
                  'string10'
                ]);
            }

            data.addRows(dataArray);

            //Options
            var options = {
                width: '100%',
                page: 'enable',
                pageSize: '3'
            };

            //Create Data View
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]);

            // Create a dashboard.
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
              document.getElementById('div_dashboard_Detail'));

            var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker1',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnIndex': 2,
                    'ui': {
                        'label': 'Business Division:'
                    }
                }
            });

            //THIS IS MY PROBLEM - SLIDER WILL NOT RENDER
            var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker2',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnIndex': 8    //Age (d)
                },
                'state': { 'lowValue': 0, 'highValue': 7 }
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'Table',
                'containerId': 'div_dashboard_Detail_chart',
                'options': {
                    showRowNumber: false,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 'auto',
                    page: 'enable',
                    pageSize: '15',
                    sort: 'enable',
                    allowHtml: true
                }
            });

            //Object Binding
            dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1, categoryPicker2], [chart]);

            // Draw the dashboard.
            dashboard.draw(view);

        }   //END  success: function (result) {
    });     //END  $.ajax({
}           //END  function drawChart()
```

What could I be missing?  I can get it to work in JSFiddle but once I put all the pieces back together in MVC it's not rendering. 
https://jsfiddle.net/hken6xco/35/

Thanks for any assistance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dashboard appears to draw fine here, even without data,

no error is received, see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

function drawChart() {
  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  //Add Columns
  data.addColumn('string', 'Review on Week');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Business Division');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Product');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Cause');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Next Step');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Carrier Reference or Responsible');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cost');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Age (d)');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Delivery Number');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Material Description');
  data.addColumn('string', '');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Actual State');

  //Create Data View
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]);

  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('div_dashboard_Detail'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker1',
      'options': {
          'filterColumnIndex': 8
      },
  });

  var categoryPicker2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker2',
      'options': {
          'filterColumnIndex': 0,     //Column used in control
          'ui': {'label': 'Actual State:'}
      }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Table',
      'containerId': 'div_dashboard_Detail_chart',
      'options': {
          showRowNumber: false,
          width: '100%',
          height: 'auto',
          page: 'enable',
          pageSize: '15',
          sort: 'enable',
          allowHtml: true
      }
  });

  //Object Binding
  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1, categoryPicker2], [chart]);

  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="div_dashboard_Detail">
  <div id="div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker1"></div>
  <div id="div_dashboard_Detail_categoryPicker2"></div>
  <div id="div_dashboard_Detail_chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there something you've left out that's causing problems? also, `jsapi/ext.js` isn't needed, just need `loader.js`... -- please share a sample of the data

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly!  The only thing I find different is how I'm getting the callback.

Comment: thinking something in the data might be causing a problem. since it works without any, can you share a sample?

Comment: I updated the post to show my callback.  That's the only difference I could find between your snippet and my code.  Could that be it?  It works when this way when I take out the slider.

Comment: I will make a stripped down version with manual data to see if that helps.  May take me a bit.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello @WhiteHat - I was able to strip it apart into just the basics.  Updated my post with full code and included a fiddle at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure what was going on.  @WhiteHat Thank you for the example.  My function initially was very complex so I separated it into a simpler version containing only the dashboard.  The only thing I found was that one variable was not defined in my more complex version.  It started working but I don't really know why.  Perhaps it was a compile error in Visual Studio because I really didn't change any of the code.

So conclusion:  the code above works and the fiddle as well.

Thanks for the help as always!!